# Converting a <button> with condition into an <input>

Tags: reactjs

I have a contact form, made with `<input>`s and a `<button>`.
I changed the `<button>` to `<input>`, but now i dont know how to add my condition `{loading ? "Sending " : "Send Message"}` inside this input. Any good solution?

my contact form code:

```
      <form
        className="app__footer-form app__flex"
        ref={form}
        onSubmit={sendEmail}
      >
        {!isFormSubmitted ? (

            //button to remove
            <button type="button" className="p-text" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              {loading ? "Sending " : "Send Message"}
            </button>

            //input to use with condition {loading ? "Sending " : "Send Message"}
            <input type="submit" value="Send" className="button" onClick={handleSubmit} />
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h3 className="head-text">Thank you in getting in touch!</h3>
          </div>
        )}
      </form>
```

Remark: i added two buttons in the render, the original  that i want to remove and the  that i want to use it with condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, when rendering this button, what specifies the *text* of the button?:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Send" className="button" onClick={handleSubmit} />
```

The rendered text on the button is `Send`.  So one can conclude that the `value` attribute specifies the text displayed.  So that's where you'd conditionally place your text:

```
<input type="submit" value={loading ? "Sending " : "Send Message"} className="button" onClick={handleSubmit} />
```